# How do I display an interactive bubble chart using Chart.js that includes a time slider

Tags: javascript, chart.js, visualization, interactive

I am relatively new to Chart.js and I'd describe myself as an amateur when it comes to coding in general. I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction when it comes to implementing the following plan as I am having a real hard time in wrapping my head around it. (tbh I don't even know if Chart.js is capable of this or if I should use another framework)

I want to create an interactive bubble chart with two "layers" that gives me a consolidated and a detailed overview of Data that changes over time. The time can be controlled via a slider below the chart. I am also planning to add info cards below that update according to the data that is currently shown. So my UI consists of three main components: The Chart itself with the two "layers", the slider that controls which data is shown and the stack of cards that can be scrolled trough horizontally.

[Here is an overview of the planned functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Bfo.jpg)

The first layer/view would be the consolidated overview:

- The size of the bubbles is influenced by the number of underlying sub topics that are shown at each given time
- The X and Y Value is the average of all the X and Y values of the sub topics that are shown at the given time
- e.g.: 1 AM, 1 Subtopic (X1=30, Y1=20) --> Size 1, X=30, Y=20; 5AM, 2 Subtopics (X1=30, Y1=20; X2=10, Y2=10) --> Size 3, X=20, Y=15)
- Under the chart and the time slider is a card that shows more information about the Topic itself
- A click on one of the cards or one the bubbles displays the subtopics that are underlying each bubble (the second layer)

### The second layer/view is the detailed view:

- The bubbles of the consolidated overview are hidden or reduced in opacity
- The bubbles on the sub topics are shown
- The cards below the chart now show a description of each sub topic
- The size for all the sub topic bubbles is the same
- The X and Y value of each bubble is fixed and doesn’t change over time
- Only the number of displayed bubbles is changed over time, which influences (as described above) the value of the according topic bubble in the consolidated view
- A click on one of the bubbles highlights it and scrolls to the corresponding card that is highlighted as well
- A click outside of the the bubbles (in the chart area) brings you back to the consolidated overview)

[Here is another visualization of the change in data over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HbWC.jpg)

My main questions are:
How should I structure the data to make this work?
Where should I start when it comes to implementing all the different elements?

I am really struggling with this one, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

I already implemented a basic bubble chart but don't know how to proceed from here